# implement syncAdapter to multiple activity in same application

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I am facing a problem for a week almost I may have downgrade but if it comes with help it does not bother me. I followed a tutorial that allows me to use Android SyncAdapter to synchronize data between the mysql database and the local Android database. Everything works fine but now I would like to resume the process to sync other data from another table in my mysql database and that's the problem. In fact I would just repeat synchronization as many times as possible in all the ancients of my application that need it.

I know that I have created so many tables in SQLite as in mysql but I do not know if I have to create two syncronization adapter, two content provider ...

In fact my code is long enough to publish it here. If anyone wants to help me, I'll send my whole sourcecode by email so he can review it and tell me how I can do that.

cordially!

Comment: use another adapter instead of using same one

Comment: already do it but it does not work

Comment: show your log details